# Why does bash freeze in windows?

Tags: bash, makefile, configure

I am running the bash program in windows which was installed along with msys and mingw. I am trying to run `./configure`. However whenever I do it the configuration freezes on `"checking whether make sets $(MAKE)"`. Can you think of any reason why and how I can fix this issue.

I ran the command

```
sh -x ./configure
```

To see exactly where it freezes. The last run command is conftest.make which has the following code

```
SHELL = /bin/sh
all:
    @echo '@@@%%%=$(MAKE)=@@@%%%'
```

When I run this command by itself in command prompt `make -f conftest.make` the output is `@@@%%%=make=@@@%%%`. However if I start bash then run the same make command it freezes.

Why does it freeze here?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Windows 7 w/MinGW.

Comment: What do you get if you run `/bin/sh -xc 'echo '\''@@@%%%=$(MAKE)=@@@%%%'\'`? And what is the last command run exactly? (`conftest.make` isn't a command by itself.)

Answer (score 1):

Are you using MinGW? If you have version 1.8* try to downgrade to 1.7. You can report this as a bug here: http://sourceforge.net/p/mingw/bugs/