# mingw cannot configure makefile in windows 7 32bit

Tags: c++, windows, makefile

I tried to compile libsndfile by using mingw. After I installed mingw and msys, I tried ”gcc -v“ command， it can return correct version.
But we I browsed to libsndfile root and "./configure", it returns error ['.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.]
Can anyone help me about this?

Comment: Are you sure you are running the configure script from the Msys shell and not the regular command prompt?

Comment: I used cmd of windows? Does msys has its own command prompt?

Comment: Yeah, the configure script won't work in the regular command prompt, you'll need to use the Msys shell.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22887999/why-does-bash-freeze-in-windows where I described mingw and msys basic usage

Comment: I tried bash or sh under msys, configure works, but still cannot make correct file, trying......

Comment: Now it can build now, we need put MinGW and MSys environment before windows ones.